# Psycopg2 .copy_from is it possible to ignore missing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql, psycopg2

0

I have several json files, donwloaded from Bigquery. And a script to modify it and export to postresql. The export part of the script is (found it here, on stackoverflow)

```
  table3.head(0).to_sql(str(table3.iat[0, 2]), engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
  conn = engine.raw_connection()
  cur = conn.cursor()
  output = io.StringIO()
  table3.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
  output.seek(0)
  cur.copy_from(output, str(table3.iat[0, 2]), null='') 
  conn.commit()
```

It exported first batch without any problems, but when I tried to export next batch, it gives me the error psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: missing data for column.
Found out, that bigquery makes events with different amount of parameters (hence columns) each day.

Is there a way to ignore missing columns or send null values if there are missing columns?

Comment: You can use `columns` in [copy_from](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) to designate the columns present in the file.

Comment: It makes around 20 tables with that script, each with different columns, and each day it can be different amount of columns unfortunately

Comment: That is what is going to need to be done. Modify the script to capture the column names and use them in `columns`.

Comment: table3.to_csv(output, sep='\t', header=False, index=False)   But this part removes header. How would it know which column it is if there are no headers? And seems that .copy_from won't remove headers

Comment: You really need to read [copy_form](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from) and [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). Short version,  using `columns` yields:  `COPY table_name (col_1, col_2, ...) FROM the_file ...`. Even if you used `HEADER` on import all that does is tell `COPY` to ignore the first row. In other words the column information in the header is not used on import in any case. All you are doing with `columns` is creating the column list for `COPY` to use to match the values in the file row.